# BeautifulSoup solution

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need your help to get "Description" content of this [URL](https://www.autotrader.ca/a/mazda/mazda3/burnaby/british%20columbia/5_49830280_20120330161920779/?showcpo=ShowCpo&ncse=no&ursrc=ts&pc=V3J%200A4&sprx=100) using BeautifulSoup in Python (as shown below).[image]

I have tried below code but it return None only!

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}

page = rq.get(url, headers=hdr)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
description = soup.find('div', {'class': 'force-wrapping ng-star-inserted'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried and i saw that `soup` doesn't has `class` *force-wrapping ng-star-inserted* because you had taken the source of site. It is different from what you saw in dev tool, to see source of site, you can press Ctr+U. Then you can see that the *description* is in `meta` tag with `name` is *description*. So, what you need to do is find this tag and take the content. For Sample:

```
res = soup.find('meta', {"name":"description"})
print(res['content'])
```